# I tried everything to make this template work but still this error: Only named blocks and mixins can appear at the top level of an extending template

Tags: node.js, templates, pug

Only named blocks and mixins can appear at the top level of an extending template. Its killing me and i cant understand why this is not working. Im new to pug and maybe i should be using something called mixins.

```
//layout.pug

doctype html
html   
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css')
    script(src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/8.7/auth0.min.js")
    link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js') 
  body
    nav.w3-bar.w3-border.w3-light-grey( role="navigation" )

      if loggedIn
        a(href="/getposts").w3-bar-item.w3-button All Customers
        a(href="/gethotposts" ).w3-bar-item.w3-button HOT Customers
        a(id="qsLogoutBtn" href="/logout").w3-bar-item.w3-button Logout
      else
        a(id="qsLoginBtn" href="/login").w3-bar-item.w3-button Login
        a(href="/getposts").w3-bar-item.w3-button All Customers
        a(href="/gethotposts" ).w3-bar-item.w3-button HOT Customers

    block content
```

---

```
//customers.pug

extends layout

block content
table.table.table-striped(style='width:700px')(align='center')
  thead
    tr
       th First Name
       th Last Name
       th Email
       th Status
  tbody
    each value in customer
      tr
         td=value.First_Name
         td=value.Last_Name
         td=value.Email
         td=value.Status
```

Comment: In `customers.pug`, indent everything under `block content` one more level. And fix the formatting of `layout.pug`—the `head` and `body` tags aren't in the right places.

Answer (score 5):

This is something that happens to me all the time when I'm in a hurry and don't check the indentation carefully.

```
block content
table.table.table-striped(style='width:700px')(align='center')
```

You need to indent your tags by two more spaces to be UNDER the `block content` and not EVEN with it:

```
extends layout

block content
  table.table.table-striped(style='width:700px')(align='center')
    thead
      tr
        th First Name
        th Last Name
        th Email
        th Status
    tbody
      each value in customer
        tr
          td=value.First_Name
          td=value.Last_Name
          td=value.Email
          td=value.Status
```